# What with iTMS transporter now?

Tags: ios, app-store, itmstransporter

I need upload .ipa to appstore, i see support it in Linux ([doc](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html))

> to the iTunes Store, Apple Books, **and App Store**.
>
> -f  or -assetFile <**.ipa** | .pkg> for macOS, Linux, and Windows uploads (for macOS notarization, use -assetFile <.dmg | .pkg | .zip>)

But now i got error

```
/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m upload -f artifacts/artifact.ipa -u "$IOS_USERNAME" -p "$IOS_PASSWORD" -v detailed
...
<main> ERROR: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/IOS/artifacts/artifact.ipa is NOT a directory. CANNOT check for invalid packages within it.
<main> ERROR: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/IOS/artifacts/artifact.ipa is NOT a directory.
```

And some coal in itms help:

```
/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -help upload
 -f <arg>                              The -f option specifies either the source
                                   directory containing package(s) (.itmsp) you
                                   want to upload or specifies a filename for a
                                   single package, including the .itmsp extension,
                                   you want to upload.
```

How to upload .ipa to app store now?

Comment: Transporter is no longer included with Xcode 11. What platform / versions are you using?

Comment: I found altool, but it's for mac only. We need upload .ipa from linux...

Comment: You might want to check out https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdAbeb95d60 Displays you a way to install iTMSTransporter on Linux to upload IPAs and similar.